# Unable to launch Internet explorer,instead tries to look for opera launcher

Tags: selenium

When I am trying to launch internet explorer 11,it tries to look for opera launcher and throws a exception as 
"Exception Occured:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Could not initialize class com.opera.core.systems.runner.launcher.OperaLauncherRunner
Command duration or timeout: 109 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.7.0_79'"

My hub file is as below:
C:
java -jar C:\Users\Public\Selenium-batch\selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -role hub -host "10.79.104.5" -port 4444
 and Node is as below:
C:
java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\Users\Public\Selenium-batch\IEDriverServer.exe  -jar C:\Users\Public\Selenium-batch\selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -role node -host "10.79.104.5" -hub http://10.79.104.5:4444/grid/register -port 5566 -browser browserName=iexplorer,platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=1 -browser browserName=firefox,platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=1 -browser browserName=chrome,platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=1 -maxSessions=3
```

It was previously working with JAVA 1.7 and a JRE1.8 got installed by mistake and when I uninstalled JRE8 and Restarted my system it is giving this error.

```
TestCase ID:174602 and Browser Name is:IE and  Iteration Id: 1
Exception Occured: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Could not initialize class com.opera.core.systems.runner.launcher.OperaLauncherRunner
Command duration or timeout: 109 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. When I added -Dos.name=windows to my hub and node batch file.Its running fine now.